# ERROR: Package GooglePlayServicesClient does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

I have added a login activity to my app with android studio however I am running into these errors:

```
Error:(11, 37) error: cannot find symbol class GooglePlayServicesClient

Error:(13, 35) error: cannot find symbol class PlusClient

Error:(20, 44) error: package GooglePlayServicesClient does not exist

Error:(21, 33) error: package GooglePlayServicesClient does not exist

Error:(35, 13) error: cannot find symbol class PlusClient

Error:(279, 12) error: cannot find symbol class PlusClient

Error:(78, 31) error: package PlusClient does not exist

Error:(160, 65) error: package PlusClient does not exist

Error:(239, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Error:(249, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Error:(262, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

I have already installed google play services in my SDK manager so I'm not sure why it's telling me the package doesn't exist.

EDIT:
Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tyler.titanaid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using android studio. Its in my dependencies.

Comment: I added my gradle file above.

Comment: @TylerPope have you solved this issue, im facing the same.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hey I just ran into this problem also. I didn't find much help so I did a lot of reading and found ( https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html ) in a small note that the GooglePlayServices API is deprecated and everyone must migrate to GoogleApi instead.

> Note: If you have an existing app that connects to Google Play
>   services with a subclass of GooglePlayServicesClient, you should
>   migrate to GoogleApiClient as soon as possible.

I guess Android Studio has not been updated to automatically input the new API instead of the old one, when adding a login activity later in development.
So anything that relies on GooglePlayServices must also be updated, including PlusClient and a bunch of others.

I've seen migrating tools on the Internet but it might just make things easier to do it yourself. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found that out as well and ended up creating my own login activity.

Comment: @TylerPope, There's a checkbox in android studio you can click to create LoginActivity without Google APIs.