# Migrate to Google API Client

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client

I picked LoginActivity template from Android Studio and started working on it. When I tried to run the project it gave me following errors:

```
Error:(10, 37) error: cannot find symbol class GooglePlayServicesClient

Error:(12, 35) error: cannot find symbol class PlusClient

Error:(18, 44) error: package GooglePlayServicesClient does not exist

Error:(19, 33) error: package GooglePlayServicesClient does not exist

Error:(33, 13) error: cannot find symbol class PlusClient

Error:(276, 12) error: cannot find symbol class PlusClient

Error:(75, 31) error: package PlusClient does not exist

Error:(157, 65) error: package PlusClient does not exist

Error:(236, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Attached is the screen shot for my Android Studio version and SDK downloaded on my machine.

[image]

[image]

I know that I need to migrate to Google API Client.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any document to do the same which provides step by step guide ?
2. Why default template provided with Android Studio are not working ?

Comment: setup target sdk as google sdk

Comment: Have you downloaded the playservices library and repo? (in SDK Manager)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: Package GooglePlayServicesClient does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310201/error-package-googleplayservicesclient-does-not-exist)